Is it normal for grain to show through 2 coats of primer on wooden doors?
Just painted an old pine door. With 2 coats of Zinsser 123, I can still see some grain coming through. Is this normal in your experience?
I haven't tried top coating with my final paint color. Should I go back and put a coat of oil or shellac based primer?


The photo is detailing the wood grain showing through the 2 coats of primer. I corrected BIN 123 to zinsser 123.

Zinsser BIN is a shellac-based paint, Bullseye 123 is water-based - So you used the water based one?

Yeah, Did the bullseye 123. Just updated the original post to correct that.

You can do another coat of primer, but I believe it is not necessary.
I have painted doors with the look you have after primer.  I just paint 3 good coats by spraying.  Or 2 with a roller and brush, then a final coat with a slightly thinned paint to make it flow easy and give a very smooth finish.
I like to use a latex semi-gloss on painted doors and mouldings.  Depending on the brand, some say thin with water, some say not to thin.  If I do thin the results have always been good, regardless of what the manufacturer recommends.

Okay right on. Good to know you've had no problem doing top coat on that. When using brush/roller, did you have a good technique for getting rid of brush marks?

Brush in one direction, the long dimension of the door. The last thinned coat should flow well to leave no brush marks.  But best results come with spraying.
